# How to prove the interarrival distribution of Poisson process is independent from one another?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

[image]
I am learning the poisson process and confused about the interarrival distribution $X_{1}, X_{2}, ⋯,$ $X_{n}$which is indepedent from one another. I can show that each of the adjacent random variables are independent($X_{1} and X_{2}$) but how can I show, for example, $X_{1}$ is indenpendent from $X_{3}$

Comment: Would you mind sharing what definition of the Poisson process are you using?

Comment: ok ,I upload the material from Sheldon_M_Ross Stochastic Process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to show $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent:
$$
P(X_3>t_3|X_1=s)=\int P(X_3>t_3|X_2=l,X_1=s)\lambda e^{-\lambda l}\,dl =  \int P(0\text{  event in  }(l,l+t_3]|X_2=l, X_1=s) e^{-\lambda l}\,dl= \int P(0\text{  event in  }(l,l+t_3]) \lambda e^{-\lambda l}\,dl = e^{-\lambda t_3}.
$$

In the third equality independent increament is used.